# How to Draw vector illustration?

Tags: vector, drawing, illustration, corel-draw

I am looking drawing lessons of the [illustrations in vector](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/476866/476866,1318492196,1/stock-vector-old-mediterranean-city-buildings-with-tile-roofs-and-the-sea-view-at-the-distance-86538679.jpg).
Or in any editor.

Comment: Welcome Jack. This question is far too broad to be answered. You would do better asking specificly targeted questions about issue you may be experiencing while learning. If you Google for "how to learn vector Illustration" there are hundreds of results to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too much simple that you don't need lessons for that. If you know how to use the path tool, you can draw anything. If you don't know how to use the path tool just click on it and try to use it. You will figure it out in 10 minutes maximum.

One thing presume that you know is, if you don't know how to draw with a pencil; illustrator is not gonna do some magic tricks to make you draw. Drawing and illustration, no matter on which platform; requires the ability draw by hand.

Comment: Altay, yes, I thought so.
Thanks for the help!